# ExtJs Date format in Grid panel

Tags: extjs

How to display date in ExtJS Gridpanel column (Date with time )

Please provide syntax.

Answer (score 2):

ExtJs provides a separate class to handle Dates and it its formatting. Have a look at [Date class](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/source/Date.html#cls-Date). There is enough examples and explanation on how to format a given date or time.

To render dates in grids according to your desired formatting you will have to use a                    `renderer` method. In you date column configuration you need to added renderer method as follows:

```
renderer: function(date){
    // process you date to your required format and return it
}
```

**Important point**: The return value from the renderer method is displayed onto the column.So, make sure you return your formatted date or time.

Answer (score 2):

**1) Create your model**

```
Ext.define('App.model.DataWithDate', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
//...
        {
            name: 'yourDate',
            type: 'date', //or Ext.data.Types.DATE
            dateFormat: 'time' //if you have standart json object with date value like timestamp 1387481693994
        }
//...
    ]
});
```

**2) For your grid config**

```
{
    columns: [
        {
            header: 'Date',
            dataIndex: 'yourDate',
            xtype:'datecolumn',
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d/m/Y H:i')
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a similar aproach as showed above by Kinjeiro, but I had to **omit the `xtype:'datecolumn'`** in order to make it work. So in my case it worked with this code:

1. Model

   ```
   this.store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
           proxy:new Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy({
               url: "php/resource.php"
           }),
       root: 'result',
       autoLoad: true,
       fields: [
               {name:'Name',type:'string',mapping:'NAME'},
               {name:'Date',type:'date',dateFormat: 'd/m/Y H:i:s',mapping:'DT_ORDER'},
               ]
   });
   ```
2. Grid config

   ```
   {
     columns: [
       { header:'<b>Name</b>',width:70,sortable:true,dataIndex:'NAME',align:'left'},
       {
         header:'<b>Date</b>',
         width:150,
         sortable:true,
         dataIndex:'DT_ORDER',
        align:'left',
        renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d/m/Y H:i:s')
       }
    ]
   }
   ```